# process.conf.xml bind xxxx_lastRun.properties parameter in SOQL in API Dataloader CLI

Tags: api, data-loader, xml, commandline

I'm building a process.conf file to extract delta view records from Salesforce.
my SOQL is looking like this now :

```
<entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="SELECT Id,FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE SystemModstamp > 2017-04-08T00:00:00Z"/>
```

Where I want to change the hard coded date to a property file value like **process.lastRunDate**=2017-04-13T15:25:09.525+0200

How do I get to this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? You want to use a different field to filter on? Or a different Datetime value? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I want to change the date value which is now hard coded in the XML. it would be more flexible if i could access the .properties file of the process where the parameter process.lastRunDate is provided.